# Почему при вводе команды ничего не выдаёт

Tags: python, discord.py

Когда я ввожу команду /tags или !tags он ничего не выводит

````
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake import TextInputStyle

# Subclassing the modal.
class MyModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        # The details of the modal, and its components
        components = [
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label="Name",
                placeholder="Foo Tag",
                custom_id="name",
                style=TextInputStyle.short,
                max_length=50,
            ),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label="Description",
                placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                custom_id="description",
                style=TextInputStyle.paragraph,
            ),
        ]
        super().__init__(title="Create Tag", components=components)

    # The callback received when the user input is completed.
    async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Tag Creation")
        for key, value in inter.text_values.items():
            embed.add_field(
                name=key.capitalize(),
                value=value[:1024],
                inline=False,
            )
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    async def on_error(self, error: Exception, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
        await inter.response.send_message(f"An error occurred!\n```{error}```")


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.slash_command()
async def tags(inter: disnake.AppCmdInter):
    """Sends a Modal to create a tag."""
    await inter.response.send_modal(modal=MyModal())


bot.run("token")
````

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, ошибка заключалась в том, что ты использовал префикс `!`, хотя команда `tags` была инициализирована как слэш команда.

я убрал `command_prefix`
и добавил некоторые разрешения для бота.

вот как выглядит мой код:

````
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake import TextInputStyle
intents = disnake.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.reactions = True
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
InteractionBot = commands.InteractionBot(intents=intents)
# Subclassing the modal.
class MyModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        # The details of the modal, and its components
        components = [
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label="Name",
                placeholder="Foo Tag",
                custom_id="name",
                style=TextInputStyle.short,
                max_length=50,
            ),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label="Description",
                placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                custom_id="description",
                style=TextInputStyle.paragraph,
            ),
        ]
        super().__init__(title="Create Tag", components=components)

    # The callback received when the user input is completed.
    async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Tag Creation")
        for key, value in inter.text_values.items():
            embed.add_field(
                name=key.capitalize(),
                value=value[:1024],
                inline=False,
            )
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    async def on_error(self, error: Exception, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
        await inter.response.send_message(f"An error occurred!\n```{error}```")




@InteractionBot.slash_command()
async def tags(inter: disnake.AppCmdInter):
    """Sends a Modal to create a tag."""
    await inter.response.send_modal(modal=MyModal())


InteractionBot.run("token")
````